# Hashing password with nestjs and mongoose crashes on production

Tags: docker, mongoose, nestjs

In my nestjs app i'm using mongoose's pre-save method to hash the password.
Locally it works fine. but on production/docker, it causes the whole nest app to crash. Here is the code:

```
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: [8, 'Password must be 8 characters or more.'],
    maxlength: 100,
  },
  username: String,
...
  phone: { type: String, default: '' },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next: mongoose.HookNextFunction) {
  try {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
      return next();
    }
    const saltRounds = 14;
    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this['password'], saltRounds);
    this['password'] = hashed;
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Again, locally it works, but in docker any user saving is causing a crash ('exited with code 0').
Do you see anything wrong in this code, or do you have a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean "crash"? Do you have a log of any error? Any more information you can share? Mongo version?  As for better way, I prefer to keep my schemas, entities, and other DAO objects as pure as possible and keep any "pre" logic in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh! I've been wasting days on this. Here is the solution. bcrypt tends to fail on nodejs apps (wait, what? bcrypt? the npm package with 487K weekly downloads? yes.)
An alternative is bcryptjs, a javascript version that is a bit slower, but hey, it works!

Get it at your nearest npm store: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs.

Here is where i found it:  https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/432